# Does the non-linear Schrodinger equation satisfy quantum mechanics rules?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, superposition, non-linear-schroedinger

Thinking about the **0+1 dimensional** (time-only) non-linear Schrodinger equation:

$$i\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \psi(t) =\kappa |\psi(t)|^2 \psi(t).$$

Treating $\psi$ as a wave function instead of a field does this satisfy the rules of quantum mechanics? Because it seems like probability would be conserved. But it is non-linear.

Yes you could treat $\psi$ as a quantum field. Then you would have a wave function $\Psi[\psi]$. But if you treated $\psi$ as a wave function by itself, would this work? (It would be a modification of quantum mechancs). If not why not?

The rules of quantum mechanics as I can make out satisfy two things:

1. Probabilities always add up to 1.
2. States that are orthogonal stay orthogonal.

Are these rules obeyed?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that's not the nonlinear Schrodinger equation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation

Comment: What happened to the term with wavefunction partially double differentiated with respect to position in that equation?

Comment: It's a one dimensional version hence no space terms. 1 dimensional = time only

Comment: If you have not spatial variation (and you don't seem to have any discrete indices either) then to conserve probabilities you must have $|\psi| = 1$, but in that case you have a stratforward linear equation and $\psi(t) = \exp(-\imath \kappa t)$. Essentially you only seem to have 1 state, so the only allowed time evolution is trivial.

Comment: @zooby That's not what "1-dimensional" typically means. One might call this "0+1-dimensional" (0 spatial dimensions, 1 time dimension) whereas most of the time "1-dimensional" motion is "1+1-dimensional."

Comment: @By Symmetry. That's true. I wonder if it could be extended with indices.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/443622/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QM, the states are elements of a projective Hilbert space. Equivalently, $\left|\psi\right>$ and $c \left|\psi\right>$ refer to the same state for any $c \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$. Your equation doesn’t preserve this symmetry, so it doesn’t satisfy the axioms of QM.