Why do people say the dynamics of quantum mechanics is always linear?
This statement seems false. An example of a non-linear equation governing the dynamics of a quantum system is the Gross-Pitaevskii equation.

You might state an example of someone saying QM is always linear, as well. That context might help.

The Gross-Pitaevskii equation is a phenomenological theory describing an emergent phenomena. The Schrodinger equation is linear. Nonlinear phenomena do exist in systems described by classical mechanics, and yet, they emerge from the Schrodinger equation which is linear.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1201/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14401/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14448/2451 and links therein.

Because SE is a linear differential equation?

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/443622/170832

@controlgroup, Steven Weinberg has referred to QM as the only physical model of the world which is exactly linear.

A converse to this question: why don't people go around saying that classical probability is always linear? It assuredly is, and such a statement is quite analogous in meaning to saying that QM is linear. I think it's a weird quirk that people find one of these two facts remarkable and not the other, and I think it must be because they were arrived at historically through quite different routes.

@N.Virgo Is dynamics of probability in classical physics really always linear? Discrete kinetic rate equations are linear, but there may be some other equations which are not. E.g. the Boltzmann transport equation does not look linear...

@JánLalinský if you mean the equation here, it's linear in $f$, which is the probability density, so that's the linearity that matters. More broadly you can find various non-linear equations in stat mech, but they are nonlinear for the same kind of reason described in TLDR's answer below - they involve large number limits that let you approximate a high dimensional linear system with a lower dimensional nonlinear one.

@N.Virgo The collision term is an integral which is not linear in $f$. But you are right that this is a low-dimensional equation, and in phase space the evolution equation is the Liouville equation, which is linear.

The Gross-Pitaevskii equation is a very good approximate (or "effective") theory for an interacting Bose Einstein Condensate, and invokes a strong assumption that all particles occupy the same wave function in the lowest energy state. This assumption is well-motivated, but it isn't 100% accurate: in the actual ground state, bosonic particles might occupy strongly overlapping but ultimately non-identical orbitals, and positing a single monolithic state inhabited by all particles ignores this very real possibility. Quantum mechanics is referred to as linear (in spite of the complexity of solving many-body systems) because the starting point in non-relativistic mechanics is always a Schroedinger equation of some sort (even in density functional theory), and the Schroedinger equation is always linear.

A derviation of the GP equation from the Schrodinger equation can be found in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.2073

@TDLR Can you mention the mathematical justification for the claim that the Schrodinger's equation is always linear?

@Yair What kind of "justification" are you expecting? The equation is linear by definition. The equation is right here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Time-dependent_equation

@Yair If $|\Psi\rangle$ is a solution and $|\Phi\rangle$ is solution, then $a|\Psi\rangle+b|\Phi\rangle$ is a solution. So it is linear.

@hft Only in case that one can rely on the derivative of sum rule. In that case you are right to say that the dynamics is linear. The thing is that this rule is not always applicable.

@Yair I don't know what you mean by "the derivative of sum rule."

@hft You imposed linearity and not showed it. If $\left|\Psi\right\rangle $ is a solution that means $\frac{d}{dt}\left|\Psi\right\rangle =-iH\left|\Psi\right\rangle $, and similarly for $\left|\Phi\right\rangle $. But this does NOT imply that $\frac{d}{dt}\left(a\left|\Psi\right\rangle +b\left|\Phi\right\rangle \right)=-iH\left(a\left|\Psi\right\rangle +b\left|\Phi\right\rangle \right)$ unless an additional condition is satisfied.

@Yair: obviously $|\Phi\rangle$ must also solve the Schroedinger equation.  The other way of looking at it is that both $\frac{d}{dt}$ and $-iH$ are linear operators, hence the kernel of $\frac{d}{dt} + iH$ is a linear subspace of Hilbert space (so if $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ are solutions, so is $a|\psi\rangle + b|\phi\rangle$: in general if the solutions form a linear subspace, it doesn't imply that the original equation is linear.)

@TDLR What you say is correct only on standard (finite dimensional) Hilbert spaces. More generally, on non-Hilbert spaces, the sum rule no longer holds and the derivative operator becomes non-linear.

@Yair: there are plenty of infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces where the derivative operator is a perfectly respectable linear operator.  Could you provide an example from, e.g., quantum field theory where the derivative is non-linear?

@TDLR The derivative operator is linear whenever its action yields a finite outcome. The simplest way to generate a problem is when the outcome is infinite, such as for $H=\delta(x)$. On the location $x=0$, the linearity property no longer exists since $\frac{d}{dt}\left|\psi\right\rangle =\infty\left|\psi\right\rangle$. It is correct that linearity holds for $x\neq0$.

I think I understand where you are coming from, but one could argue that linearity everywhere except a set of measure zero is essentially linearity.  Also, I suspect that most physicists (and probably most mathematicians) would argue that the proper domain of $H=\delta(x)$ is the set of functions that vanish at $x=0$, where the action of $H$ is trivially linear. Do you have an ideas for how to meaningfully extend the Schroedinger-type equation $i \partial_t\psi(x,t) = \delta(x) \psi(x,t)$ beyond this domain?

The first sentence that you wrote is correct only when superficially imposing that the space is $L^{2}$. Otherwise, the measure-0 has a non-trivial effect that cannot be neglected. If you don't like the delta function, you can also look at the case of vectors living on an infinite dimensional spaces. Generally speaking, $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}v_{n}(t)\left|n\right\rangle +\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}u_{m}(t)\left|m\right\rangle \right)\neq\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}v_{n}(t)\left|n\right\rangle +\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}u_{m}(t)\left|m\right\rangle $.

The linearity of quantum comes from The Principle of Superposition and is one of the most fundamental ideas in Quantum Theory.
In the book "The Principles of Quantum Theory" chapter I, Paul Dirac argue about this principle. After giving some examples of experimental situations that can't be explained by Classical Mechanics, he says the following (ch I, section 4 pg 11)

There remains an overall criticism that one may make to the whole scheme, namely, that in departing from determinacy of the classical theory a great complication is introduced into the description of Nature, which is a undesirable feature. This complication is undeniable, but it is offset by a great simplification, provided by The general Principle of Superposition of states, which we shall now go on to consider.

We could conclude two things:

As a principle, it can't be "derived" or concluded as a consequence of previous ideas. We accept it as a feature of the new scheme, in the same basis that we accept to depart from the determinacy of the classical theory.
it comes as a simplification. We are not searching for the most complicated description of Nature, but the most accurate one. There would be no reason, for a matter of mathematical generalization, to consider a more complicated scheme, if this simple one already explain the natural phenomena.

Dirac mentions the Principle of Superposition before to define the mathematical structure of the theory and even before the definition of state.

Do you know of some critical review of Dirac's book? He was a very original thinker, but sometimes it's hard to see why he makes certain statements or agree with him. His argument about superposition can be applied to many other non-quantum parts of physics, e.g. the Liouville equation in statistical physics, or kinetic rate equations, but nobody thinks math simplicity there is a good tradeoff for rejecting deterministic microscopic models; instead, we have both. A non-linear equation in QT would be much better physically, as it could maybe describe projection after measurement.

Agreeing or not with Dirac, his book influenced a lot the development of quantum theory as it is. We can disagree and propose new ideas, like a non-linear QT as you mentioned, but it will not change the theory like it is, just will create another one. The question is tricky: "why do people say the dynamics of QT is always linear?" Because it was developed that way. We can disagree with Dirac and the way he did things, but we are working on his shoulders.

Physicists believe that quantum mechanics is perfectly linear. But when you apply assumptions, or leave out parts of a system it might appear nonlinear. So if you were to describe the entire universe using the ket $|\Psi\rangle$, the universe would evolve according to
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\Psi\rangle=\hat H|\Psi\rangle,$$
where $\hat H$ is a linear operator.
You might remember the time energy was first introduced to you in school. Energy is always conserved? Why does everything seem to slow down to a halt when left alone? Why is it possible to discharge a battery without doing any useful work? Although energy is always conserved$^\dagger$, in many systems it appears to be lost because it enteres the microscopic degrees of freedom. In those cases it is often simpler to act as if the energy is lost. Similarly, it is sometimes simpler to treat quantum mechanics as nonlinear.
$\dagger$ (except sometimes in general relativity)

The linear nature of quantum mechanics enters in the actual formulation of the theory.
It isn't so much that this is an arbtrary decision, but is really enshrined in postulates of the theory itself. There are different presentations of those postulates but the key point is:

Postulates are hypotheses that cannot be proven. If no discrepencies
are found in nature then the postulate becomes an axiom...

These postulates and axioms are being challenged and tested regularly with results of experimentation regarding the possibility of nonlinearities in electromagnetism being updated as recently as this month November 2024.
Nonlinearity does in fact enter into the mix when dealing with practical open quantum systems where unitary evolution is not preserved.  Most commonly one sees this in the application of a version of the Linblad Master Equation that is sometimes called the NonLinear Linblad Equation
So in short, quantum mechanics is by definition linear.  Whether all of nature is quantum is a long standing argument.  For practical applications the rigidness of linearity as a constraint is relaxed particularly when it is not practical to fully define a closed qauntum system.

Quantum theory is linear only in part, when the Schroedinger equation applies. There are processes in QT where it does not apply, e.g. projection of spin state of single atom in SG magnet. Projection cannot be described as linear evolution.

See also https://www.sigmapisigma.org/sites/default/files/files/publications/2013/elegant-connections-spin-statistics-theorem.pdf

People(even high credentialed ones) say false things all the time. Gross-Pitaevskii is an approximate replacement of the Schr. equation.The statement you ask about is implicitly about QT in general (the fundamental laws). It means time evolution of $\psi$ is given always by linear equation in $\psi$. It is true the Schroedinger equation (or similar fundamental equation giving evolution in time) is linear in $\psi$. But of course, time evolution in quantum theory is more complicated. Consistent account of single system before and after measurement has to involve also reduction of system's $\psi$ (projection, collapse), which isn't a linear process. This means $\psi$ across measurement can't be described by the linear Schroedinger equation. So measurement is special process, and we have no good mathematical description for it (the measurement problem), only the projection postulate, defining the appropriate final $\psi$ based on the result obtained from observation. So the statement that the whole theory is linear is not really true.
So you can tell, if the person is claiming whole QT is perfectly linear, they either aren't aware of the measurement problem, or they are, but believe it is solved by doubling down on the linear evolution, usually given by the Schr. equation. This really isn't possible, but some people claim it is, if we believe there are many worlds and $\psi$ and Schr. equation describe all these worlds at once. But they do not seem to be able to explain (so that other agree with them) why experiments have definite results implying non-linear evolution of $\psi$. E.g. those obtained in a measurement of spin component of silver atom in the SG-type experiment. There isn't a good explanation for how linear evolution of $\Psi$ of the whole super-system makes the effective $\psi$ evolve as if projection of $\psi$ happens (which is a nonlinear operation).

In general, this statement is incorrect. Quantum mechanics predicts the time evolution of states in a probabilistic way, and as such it has to be unitary.
However, on infinite dimensional spaces unitary operators are non linear unless the Hamiltonian is bounded a self-adjoint operator. A more precise statement is to say that the Schrodinger equation predicts a linear regime. Mathematically speaking, the property of linearity at a given time $t$ holds if
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\left|\psi(t)\right\rangle +\left|\phi(t)\right\rangle \right)\,=\,\frac{d}{dt}\left|\psi(t)\right\rangle +\frac{d}{dt}\left|\phi(t)\right\rangle ,$$
for states $\left|\psi(t)\right\rangle ,\left|\phi(t)\right\rangle \in\mathcal{H}$. The linearity rule above works only when dealing with states that satisfy
$$\left\Vert \frac{d}{dt}\left|\psi(t)\right\rangle \right\Vert \,<\,M\left\Vert \left|\psi(t)\right\rangle \right\Vert ,$$ with $M\in\mathbb{R}$. The states $\left|\psi\right\rangle $ not satisfying the boundness condition are outside of the scope of the linear regime.
In order to make things more concrete and address the comment below, one can look at the Kronig–Penney potential for a particle in a one-dimensional lattice,
$$V(x)\,=\,A\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-na).$$
The corresponding time evolution operator, $e^{-iHt}$, has an indefinite meaning for states $\left|x\right\rangle $ with singular position eigenvalue of $x=na$, so the condition $\left\Vert \frac{d}{dt}e^{-iHt}\left|x_{0}\right\rangle \right\Vert <M\left\Vert \left|x_{0}\right\rangle \right\Vert $ is not satisfied. In other words, we are getting outside of Hilbert space formalism for any given time $t>0$. Since these measure-0 "holes" are outside of the domain of $H$ one cannot rely on Stone's theorem to guarantee unitarity there, and also linearity broken as well.

Comments on the proper definition of linearity in infinite-dimensional systems have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
